# How can I create a dict of dicts from 3 columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe `df` with columns `id`, `col1`, `col2` (note there are no duplicate `id`)

I want to create a dict of dicts. The outer dict is keyed by the value of `id` from `df`. The inner dict has keys `col1` and `col2` with corresponding values from `df`.

I know you can use `to_dict` to create an un-nested dict with 2 columns, but I don't know how to do this with 3 columns and nested dicts.

suppose `df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [0, 1], "col1": [1.1, 2.2], "col2":[2.0, 3.0]})`

I want to have an algorithm that gives me

```
d = {
  0: {"col1": 1.1, "col2": 2.0}.
  1: {"col1": 2.2, "col2": 3.0}.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
df.set_index('id').to_dict('index')
```

If you have other columns:

```
df.set_index('id')[['col1', 'col2']].to_dict('index')
```

Output:

```
{0: {'col1': 1.1, 'col2': 2.0},
 1: {'col1': 2.2, 'col2': 3.0}}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention my `df` has other columns as well, but I tihnk I can just do `df[["id", "col1", "col2"]].set_index('id').to_dict('index')`?

Comment: Indeed, you could slice the columns of interest. Alternative: `df.set_index('id')[['col1', 'col2']].to_dict('index')`.